# Indent X number of spaces in visual mode, vim

Tags: vim

In visual mode I really like being able to highlight a block of text then use `>` to indent the block text. The defalut indent space for this seems to be a \t.

Is there a way to alter this command or another command to indent a highlighted block of text X number of spaces,
for instance if I only want to indent 2 spaces instead of an entire tab width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:'<,'>norm I<space><space>
```

Does what you want.

Comment: Just mentioning that you don't actually "type" out `:'<,'>`, you just highlight the line with `V` and then hit `:`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I usually add something like "('<,'> being automatically added for you)" but forgot it this time.

Answer (score 2):

You can change this behavior by adding in your `.vimrc`

```
set shiftwidth=2
```

It tells indentation caused by `>` and `<` operators is 2 characters wide.

You can also consider

```
set tabstop=4
```

Telling Vim that a `\t` is equivalent to 4 spaces, and

```
set expandtab
set noexpandtab
```

Which tells Vim to (or not to) automatically replace `\t` by the equivalent amount of spaces when pressing Tab key or when indenting with `>`.

Comment: I recommend this pod cast, it explains how these things work really well: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to vertically select a column in the block with Ctrl+V,
then `I` to insert vertically and then type one (or any number) space and

---

To be more robust:

If you can't read Chinese, ignoring them in the comment will be OK.

```
" https://superuser.com/questions/694564/indent-x-number-of-spaces-in-visual-mode-vim/1718910#1718910
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=0
        " au AG BufEnter  * if &ft == 'lua' | set tabstop=4 | endif
                                " filetype滞后于BufEnter吧
        au AG BufEnter  *.lua   setlocal tabstop=4
                    " 有些复制来的lua代码, 要加这个autocmd才能让tabstop=4
        au AG BufEnter  *.man  setlocal ft=man
                                " 没生效, 现在BufEnter *.man文件后, &ft是nroff
set shiftround

" move 4 spaces
    nno > >>
    nno < <<

    vno < <gv
    vno > >gv

" move 2 spaces
    nno <M-.> <cmd>call RightN(2)<cr>
        func! RightN(n_space)
            set noshiftround
            normal mt
            exe 'normal I'..repeat(' ', a:n_space)
            normal `t
            set shiftround
        endf

    nno <M-,> <cmd>call LeftN(2)<cr>
        func! LeftN(n_space)
            set backspace=indent,start
                " 刨掉eol,
            set noshiftround

                normal mt
                exe 'normal I'..repeat('', a:n_space)
                normal `t

            set shiftround
            set backspace=indent,start,eol
        endf


        vno <M-.> <cmd>call V_RightN(2)<cr><esc>
            func! V_RightN(n_space)
                set noshiftround

                mark t
                normal gv
                exe "'<,'>normal I"..repeat(' ', a:n_space)
                normal `t
                normal gv
                normal gv
                " see:     The type  of the old area is used (character, line or blockwise).

                set shiftround
            endf

        vno <M-,> <cmd>call V_LeftN(2)<cr>
            func! V_LeftN(n_space)
                set noshiftround

                mark t
                exe "'<,'>normal I"..repeat('', a:n_space)
                normal `t
                normal gv
                normal gv

                set shiftround
            endf

" move 1 space
    nno <M-_> mnI <esc>`nl
    vno <M-_> mnI <esc>`nlgv


" 状态栏有时提示:
    " 3 lines <ed 1 tim
    " 3 lines >ed 1 tim
" >ed is just short for "shifted"


set expandtab
```